# Dynamic lengths of list applied as operators in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, operators

If I have an list like so:

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and df like so

[image: original df]

and I'd like to create a new column in a df based on a,b,c, I can do something like this:

```
df['new_col_1'] = df[myList[0]] & df[myList[1]] & df[myList[2]]
```

A boolean is present in each of the cells, so outcome is either True/False.

The problem is sometimes the 'myList' may not be length 3, but 2, 4 etc. Is there a simple way to compensate for varying lengths of myList?

In addition, as soon as 'new_col_1' is set to True (in this case only for 'mnl'), then this should set all of its columns (so a,b,c) to FALSE, because 'new_col_1' is now TRUE. The outcome should be:

[image]

Comment: can you create a sample dataframe and show us how the expected output should be?

Comment: @anky_91: just added...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all let's create the dataframe and the list from your example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    ],
    index=["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mnl"],
    columns=list("abcde")
).applymap(bool)

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Then let's split the problem in two parts

**Part 1: Create `new_col`**

You basically need to take all columns from `my_list` and perform an `and` operation row-wise. You can do it with `all(axis=1)`:

```py
df["new_col"] = df[my_list].all(axis=1)
```

The result would be:

```
         a      b      c      d      e  new_col
abc  False  False  False  False  False    False
def  False  False  False  False   True    False
ghi  False  False  False   True  False    False
jkl  False  False  False  False  False    False
mnl   True   True   True  False  True     True
```

**Part 2: Update table based on `new_col`**

This is can be done with the `loc`operator. We want to affect all rows where `new_col` is `True` and set `False` to columns in `my_list`:

```py
df.loc[df["new_col"], my_list] = False
```

The result will be:

```
         a      b      c      d      e  new_col
abc  False  False  False  False  False    False
def  False  False  False  False   True    False
ghi  False  False  False   True  False    False
jkl  False  False  False  False  False    False
mnl  False  False  False  False  True     True
```

Comment: I think this looks very much like a solution I need - thank you! Just one thing (I should have given a better example): Say if cell "mnl / e" is True, I don't want this set to False, but to stay as is. How can I do that?

Comment: You are welcomed. I changed the answer to only set the columns in `my_list` to False. If this answer solves your question you could mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure this out myself before you changed it, I marked your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `for` loop would suffice here.

A code-golfier solution would be using `reduce`

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

df['new_col_1'] = reduce(operator.and_, map(df.__getitem__, myList))
```

Answer (score 2):

here is another way using [`df.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) and [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) (data courtesy @villoro)

```
c = df.dot(df.columns).eq(''.join(my_list)) #assuming all the columns are booleans
final = pd.DataFrame(np.where(c[:,None],False,df),columns=df.columns,index=df.index)
                                                             .assign(new_col1=c)
```

---

```
print(final)  

         a      b      c      d      e  new_col1
abc  False  False  False  False  False     False
def  False  False  False  False   True     False
ghi  False  False  False   True  False     False
jkl  False  False  False  False  False     False
mnl  False  False  False  False  False      True
```